# Cannot format newly installed HD in MacBook Pro mid 2012 13"

Tags: macbook-pro

I Just replaced Mac HD with HGST (a Western Digital co) TravelStar 500gb. I accessed DU using start+option key and start+command R key, but still cannot format. In DU I used the Erase tab, clicked the erase button, waited while it cycled, about 10 minutes, but did not format. Message was cannot erase. I followed steps in many forums. Can anyone tell me what else I need to do.

Comment: you can not format a drive from with in it self.

Comment: I am using the disk utility. I cannot partition the new HD either.

Comment: Quick question...what is the "start-command-r" key sequence?  It should just be "Command-R."  Also, during the Internet Recovery boot process, it should ask you for your Wi-Fi settings.  Can you confirm that this is happening?

Comment: I'm sorry it is command + R, it allows me to select a wireless network so that I can access th OS X Utilities area. It detects the new hard drive, but when I select the new hard drive, rename it, and try to use the Erase button, it runs its cycle but comes back with a message erase failed. I cannot format the new HD. It will not allow me to partition either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in internet recovery you **should** be able to format the drive as it downloads a minimal system on a RAM disk (from what I have heard...) and boots from that.

That error needs some more diagnostic info in order to help. Do you still have the old drive you can put back in and boot from? Then an external case to put the new drive in? If so do that and see if you can format it that way. If not report back with some more details.

Comment: I have the old drive but do not have an ext drive case or another MacBook. I was told by the apple Genius Bar that my old hard drive was "failing", that is why I bought the new HD. After I installed the new HD, i followed the directions exactly. "Start" held Command + R, established a connection, reached the OS X util page, selected the new HD, renamed it and clicked the Erase button. It ran its cycle and returned a failed to erase message.

Comment: Without the external case we can't proceed troubleshooting. So I would take it up with the place you bought the drive and get a new one and hope for the best.